# I'm looking for the best intelligent search extinsion

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, advanced-search, search-criteria

I'm looking for the best intelligent search for Magento 2 CE. I need it to show the result fast and  fix the issue if customer search for the product by miss spelling not the exact product name and got product not found. I need it to show the result with the closest product name and other recommendations products.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look the Smile Elasticsuite extension, it is the most popular search extension for Magento 2.

Go to github repository to read more about this extension: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/